# An Urn Contains Ten Balls - Combinatorics Questions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains ten balls of which three are black and seven are white.  The following game is played:  At each trial a ball is selected at random, its color is noted, and it is replaced along with two additional balls of the same color.  What is the probability that a black ball is selected in each of the first three trials?

In the first trial, we have a $$\frac{3}{10}$$ chance of getting a black. In the next trial, because we add two additional balls of the same color, we have a $$\frac{5}{12}$$ chance. And finally, in the third trial, it would be $$\frac{7}{14}$$

My final answer would then be $$\frac{3}{10}*\frac{5}{12}*\frac{7}{14}$$

Is this the right approach to solving this question?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: Indeed.  When you have $10-n$ red and $n$ black balls in the urn, the probability of selecting three black balls in the first three such draws is:$$\dfrac{n}{10}\dfrac{(n+2)}{12}\dfrac{(n+4)}{14}$$ And when $n=3$ ... you get what you got.